# How to add help pages to an R package?

Tags: r, package, documentation

I'd like to create my own package that would contain five datasets. However, I don't know how to add several help pages to a documentation section that would describe these datasets. For now, I managed to make only one help page for a single UCDP dataset.

To make my problem clearer, I add a screenshot from the dslabs package [image: 1] (this is how I want my documentation to look like) and a screenshot of what I currently have in my package [image: 2].

I already have the needed datasets stored as RData files. The only obstacle is documentation.

Comment: Have you read https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#documenting-data?

Comment: How did you create the help file you have?  The same process should work for each of your other datasets.  Do you get any errors or warnings when you try that?

Comment: @r2evans thank you for the link, it was useful!